# FileSystemException error in flutter: Flutter app not running at all

Tags: flutter, dart, apk, filesystemexception

Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly: "FileSystemException: Cannot retrieve modification time, path =
'C:\Administrative\Projects\mics_function12\pubspec.yaml' (OS Error: The operation completed successfully.
, errno = 0)".
A crash report has been written to C:\Administrative\Projects\mics_function12\flutter_03.log.

`flutter pub cache repair`
`flutter pub get`
`flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`

Answer (score 0):

In my pubspec.yaml file, I had something like:

```
name: myApp
description: A new flutter project
```

so, I replaced it with:

```
name: yourProjectFolderName
description: A new flutter project
```